# How to make a keras model return nothing on making prediction when no object is found in an image?

Tags: python-3.x, keras

I have made a Keras model that can predict 5 types of plants (mint, basil, aubergine, strawberry, tomato). Model accuracy is 97% which I am happy about but the problem is when I feed it image that does not contain any of the previous labels it still make a prediction and returns false result. Is there a way to make a model to return nothing or something like message saying no labels in the pic?

Comment: Yes, there are multiple approaches, one of them is simply to create a no-class class.

Comment: Can you explain further please?

Comment: I will add a link that could provide some explanation and code too. https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/9066

Comment: There are many ways on how one can deal with this problem. [Here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1810.01861) one may find a simple method on how to deal with this (I am an author ;) )